# Laravel - S3 multiple file zip and download

Tags: php, laravel, loops, foreach

Is there any way to loop or perform some foreach action inside return in Laravel?
I have this package https://github.com/stechstudio/laravel-zipstream for zip downloading from s3. All works for single file and for multiple, but only when each files are provided in separate line.

```
use Zip; 
public function z4()
    {
    return Zip::create("package.zip")
                ->add("s3://testbucket/images/26/17/full/BS288.jpg", "BS288.jpg")
                ->add("s3://testbucket/images/26/17/full/BS289.jpg", "BS289.jpg")
                ->add("s3://testbucket/images/26/17/full/BS290.jpg", "BS290.jpg")
    }
```

but how to make this with data from database

```
$photos = DB::table('gallery_image')
                ->where('folder_id','=',$id)
                ->select('original_name')->get();
```

This is array returned from $photos:

```
  Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1017 ▼
        #items: array:131 [▼
          0 => {#1025 ▼
            +"original_name": "BS288.jpg"
          }
          1 => {#1022 ▼
            +"original_name": "BS289.jpg"
          }
          2 => {#1026 ▼
            +"original_name": "BS290.jpg"
          }
```

this code will return always one file

```
foreach($photos as $image) {
     
            return Zip::create("package.zip", [
                "s3://asystentfotografa/images/26/17/full/".$image->original_name, 
              ]);
 }
```

Comment: Do the images always get stored to the same directory path (i.e. `images/26/12/full/`), or can that differ and if it does, where do you store that information?

Comment: path is stored inside db. s3 bucket will be always this same, images folder as well, next I have gallery_id and folder_id this can change. Folder_ID and Gallery_ID  will come as variable from blade view. then this should be like this is real live s3://asystentfotografa/images/$gallery_id/$folder_id/full/$image->original_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to change the `field names` I have used as they might not be accurate, however, what about something like the following?

```
public function z4()
{
    $photos = DB::table('gallery_image')
                ->where('folder_id','=',$id)
                ->select('original_name')->get();

    $zip = Zip::create('package.zip');

    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $zip->add('s3://testbucket/images/' . $photo->gallery_id . '/' . $photo->folder_id . '/full/' . $photo->original_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadZipImage() {
        $assets = Asset::get(['photos', 'qr']);
        
        $zip = Zip::create("All photos.zip");
        foreach ($assets as $asset) {
            # code...
            if($asset->qr != null){
                $zip->add('s3://somebucket/qrcode/'.$asset->qr, "qrcode/" .  $asset->qr);
            }
            if($asset->photos !=null){
                $zip->add('s3://somebucket/photos/'.$asset->photos, "photos/".$asset->photos );
            }
        }
        
        return $zip;
    }
```

Above code saves QR photos on *qrcode* folder, and photos on *photos* folder.

dont forget to changes the name of the bucket. It works smooth on me.